# How to fix Mismatched tag error in XML output

Tags: doxygen

When processing the bignum.h file to XML (or HTML), the tags are not properly ordered. This causes an error with the sphinx breathe parser.

```
/doxygen/xml\dd/da2/bignum_8h.xml: mismatched tag: line 2599, column 172
```

The line causing the failure is:

```
at most 2<sup>-2*\p rounds</sup>.
```

Generated XML is:

```
2<superscript>-2*<computeroutput>rounds</superscript></computeroutput>
```

The workaround is to add space as seen below.

```
at most 2<sup>-2*\p rounds </sup>.
```

Newly generated HTML is:

```
2<superscript>-2*<computeroutput>rounds</computeroutput> </superscript>
```

The Doxygen output for HTML for this file is found here and exhibits the same mismatch (however a browser is tolerant of it) https://tls.mbed.org/api/bignum_8h.html

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using. This problem is a known issue, see https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8706

Comment: Alternatively you can use: ```at most 2<sup>-2*`rounds`</sup>.```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue and tip. We were using Doxygen 1.9.2 when we first discovered the issue and test 1.9.3 with no change in this behavior.